# My CSS is not working properly when trying to display a div element when a p element is hovered

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown navigation system on my website, and it works fine, but I noticed that when I hovered below the dropdown text it would display the dropdown anyway. ([jsfiddle of before](https://jsfiddle.net/tx4suer9/)) I wanted to change that, so I tried changing `#dropdown:hover #dropdown-content` to `#dropdown p:hover #dropdown-content`. But I am not getting any results.

```css
#nav-container {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 3px 3px;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  position: sticky;
}

#nav-items {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -45px;
}

#nav-items li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 400px;
}

#group1 {
    display: inline-block;
}

#dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#dropdown p { 
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; 
  font-size: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin: auto auto auto auto;
}

#dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px auto auto auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #575757; 
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #D3D3D3;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

#dropdown-content img {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  user-drag: none; 
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.nav-dropdown-container {width: 400px;}

#dropdown-content p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; 
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#dropdown p:hover #dropdown-content {  /* CHANGES HERE */
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
  padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
  <div id="nav-container">
    <center>
      <ul id="nav-items">
        <li>
          <div id="group1">
            <div class="nav-dropdown-container">
              <div id="dropdown">
                <p>Test</p>
                <div id="dropdown-content">
                  <p>Test</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </center>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried everything, from putting the `p` element in it's own div to putting the `p` element in the `ul` element. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this CSS selector `#dropdown>p:hover ~ #dropdown-content` :

```css
#nav-container {
 display: table;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation {
 height: 100px;
 padding: 10px 3px 3px;
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
 position: sticky;
}

#nav-items {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: -45px;
}

#nav-items li {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 400px;
}

#group1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

#dropdown {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

#dropdown p { 
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; 
 font-size: 35px;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 margin: auto auto auto auto;
}

#dropdown-content {
 position: absolute;
 margin: 10px auto auto auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #575757; 
 border-radius: 8px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #D3D3D3;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 transition-property: all;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

#dropdown-content img {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 user-drag: none; 
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.nav-dropdown-container {width: 400px;}

#dropdown-content p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; 
 font-size: 30px;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#dropdown>p:hover ~ #dropdown-content {
 opacity: 1;
 max-height: 500px;
 padding-top: 1em;
   padding-bottom: 1em;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


#dropdown:hover #dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
  <div id="nav-container">
    <center>
      <ul id="nav-items">
        <li>
          <div id="group1">
            <div class="nav-dropdown-container">
              <div id="dropdown">
                <p>Test</p>
                <div id="dropdown-content">
                  <p>Test</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </center>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. Also if I may ask, what is the difference between `#dropdown>p:hover ~ #dropdown-content` and `#dropdown p:hover #dropdown-content`?

Comment: You're welcome, the first will target the `#dropdown-content` that is a **sibling** of `#dropdown>p:hover`, the second one will select  `#dropdown-content` that is a **child** of `#dropdown p:hover`.

Comment: You can replace my `#dropdown>p:hover` by your `#dropdown p:hover` if you want. Mine means *"target  `p` that is **the first child** of #dropdown"*, yours means *"target `p` that is **a child** of #dropdown"*

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css selector : `~`

it's going to be like that now:

```css
#dropdown p:hover ~ #dropdown-content {  /* CHANGES HERE */
 opacity: 1;
 max-height: 500px;
 padding-top: 1em;
   padding-bottom: 1em;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
}
```